# Converting File input to text in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, file, typeerror

I'm programming a simple JavaScript page to get a file from the user and convert it to a data variable of either binary or text. When I use my code in a click event handler of a button,  I get this error:

**Uncaught TypeError: file.getAsText is not a function at HTMLButtonElement.sendfButton.onclick**

First I browse and select a file, then click on *send* button.

This is my html input and button:

```
            <tr>
            <td>
                <button type="button" class="control-button" id="send-file-button">SEND-FILE</button> 
            </td>
            <td>
                    <input type='file' id='myfileinput' multiple><br>
                    <div id='output'>


            </td>
        </tr>
```

Here are my variables:

```
                var sendfButton = document.getElementById("send-file-button");
            var fileInput = document.getElementById("myfileinput");
```

And here is my click event handler:

```
sendfButton.onclick = function ()
                {
                var files = fileInput.files;
                var accept = {
                binary : ["image/png", "image/jpeg"],
                text   : ["text/plain", "text/css", "application/xml", "text/html" , "text/txt"]
                };
                var file;
                    if (conn && conn.open)
                    {
                        console.log('in1');
                         //convert a file to bytes then send it
                        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
                        {
                            console.log('in2');
                            file = files[i];
                            // if file type could be detected
                            if (file !== null) 
                            {
                                console.log('in3');
                                if (accept.binary.indexOf(file.type) > -1) 
                                {
                                    console.log('in binary');
                                    // file is a binary, which we accept
                                    var data = file.getAsBinary();
                                    console.log(data + 'dtat');
                                } 
                                else if (accept.text.indexOf(file.type) > -1) 
                                {
                                    console.log('in text');
                                // file is of type text, which we accept
                                var data = file.getAsText();
                                console.log(data + 'dqata');
                                // modify data with string methods
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        console.log('out' + data);
                        conn.send(data);
                        console.log("fSent: " + data);
                        addMessage("<span class=\"selfMsg\">Self: </span> " + data);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        console.log("failed fsend");
                    } 
                }
```

It seems to work when I run the code directly, but not when it is activated inside of the button event handler.
**Code 2**
i add filereader but still there is a bug :

```
sendfButton.onclick = function ()
                {
                var files = fileInput.files;
                var accept = {
                binary : ["image/png", "image/jpeg"],
                text   : ["text/plain", "text/css", "application/xml", "text/html" , "text/txt"]
                };
                var file;
                    if (conn && conn.open)
                    {
                        console.log('in1');
                         //convert a file to bytes then send it
                        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
                        {
                            console.log('in2');
                            file = files[i];
                            var readers = new FileReader();
                            // if file type could be detected
                            if (file !== null) 
                            {
                                console.log('in3');
                                if (accept.binary.indexOf(file.type) > -1) 
                                {
                                    console.log('in binary');
                                    // file is a binary, which we accept
                                    var data = readers.readAsBinaryString(file);
                                    console.log(data + 'dtat');
                                } 
                                else if (accept.text.indexOf(file.type) > -1) 
                                {
                                    console.log('in text');
                                // file is of type text, which we accept
                                var data = readers.readAsText(file);
                                console.log(data + 'dqata');
                                // modify data with string methods
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        console.log('out' + data);
                        conn.send(data);
                        console.log("fSent: " + data);
                        addMessage("<span class=\"selfMsg\">Self: </span> " + data);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        console.log("failed fsend");
                    } 
                }
```

it returns 
**undefined**

Comment: Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page. Please include details like at *least* where the error is actually triggered. Otherwise we have to guess.

Comment: `file` is just a handle to a file, not an actual file. You need to use a `fileReader` to read the file that `file` is associated with. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader

Comment: i approved my code with adding filereader but there is a bug it returns undefined i edited my question so you can see my second code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `File.getAsText()` method is obsolete. The File object is a specific kind of a Blob, so you can use the `Blob.text()` method instead. Replace `file.getAsText()` in your code with `await file.text()`.

Edit: Another option that has better browser support is to use [FileReader.readAsText()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsText). Your code would look something like this:

```js
var button = document.getElementById("send-file-button");
var fileInput = document.getElementById("myfileinput");
var output = document.getElementById("output");

button.onclick = function () {
  var files = fileInput.files;
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function () {
    output.innerText = reader.result;
  };
  if(files[0]) {
    // This does not return the text. It just starts reading.
    // The onload handler is triggered when it is done and the result is available.
    reader.readAsText(files[0]);
  }
};
```

```html
<input type='file' id='myfileinput' multiple>
<button type="button" class="control-button" id="send-file-button">SUBMIT-FILE</button> 
<div id='output'>
```

Comment: no change i got this instead Uncaught _TypeError: file.Text is not a function
    at HTMLButtonElement.sendfButton.onclick_

Comment: text() needs to be lower case.

Comment: You can also try using FileReader.readAsText() as decribed here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsText

Comment: i approve my code with adding filereader but there is a bug it returns **undefined** i edited my question so you can see my second code.

Comment: The readAsText method does not return the text. It just starts reading. The onload method of the reader is an event handler that is triggered when the reader is finished and the result property of the reader is available. I updated my answer to demonstrate this.

Comment: thanks ! it works but how can use it as variable ? as string or something.

Comment: Inside the onload handler function, reader.result contains the text string from the file and can be assigned to a variable and used however you like. You can't use it when you call reader.readAsText() because it takes time to read the file and you need to wait until it is done. When it is done, it will call the onload handler and you can access the result then, and continue there with whatever you were going to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative for a different string result, but here your can send it to your backend rest. file variable is from the File api.

```
var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function () {
    // send console result to your backend
    console.log(reader.result.split(',')[1]);
  };
  if(file) {
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }
```